# change application display name in windows Phone Application using globalization and Localization?

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization, globalization, windows-phone-8.1

I try to change my windows phone application display name using globalization and localization. I use 2 language for now. Is it possible to change display name in WMAppManifest.xml ?

I write my application name in Turkish, and I want application name is changing to English in phone's menu if phone is in English.

I'm programming Windows Phone 8.1 app.

Comment: Hope [this](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/02/01/tips-for-localizing-windows-phone-8-xaml-apps-part1.aspx) article would help you with this. It worked for me.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? Cause I was looking at a similar problem. And the only links I'm getting are related to Win 8.0 or silverlight nothing with regards to winrt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) article is the first hit when you enter "localize application display name on windows phone" on Google. You have all the information you need there.